# Number to words decryption

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, encryption

Given the following code:

```
list = [1, 0 ,3]

def decrypt(text, alphabet):
    decrypt_final = ""

    for j in alphabet:
        aindex = alphabet.index(j)
        for i in list:
            if aindex == i:
                decrypt_final = decrypt_final + str(j)

    print(decrypt_final)

decrypt("103", "abcde")
```

When the code is run, the result is `"abd"` which is not what I want. I am trying to decrypt the number 103 based on the alphabet range of `"abcde"` and the correct result should be `"bad"` if the input is `"103"`.

What my code above was trying to do was to look into the list (the numbers in the list come from another function which I did not include to simplify this), and if the list number matches the index of the alphabet, to output the alphabet. Unfortunately, the output order is wrong.

Will appreciate some guidance.

Comment: In your function you dont use the parameter `text`.

Comment: You don't want/need to be looping over `alphabet` here. You want to loop over each character in `text` convert that to a number, and then index that position in `alphabet`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the following should work

```py
def decrypt(text, alphabet):
    decrypt_final = ""
    # convert text to list of indices
    str_to_int = [int(i) for i in text]
    for j in str_to_int:
        decrypt_final += alphabet[j]

    print(decrypt_final)

decrypt("103", "abcde")
```

You just convert the text(`"103"`) to a list of indices.

Comment: Looping over `text` to produce a list to loop over seems a bit roundabout. Just loop over `text` and convert the current character to `int` as you go.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, exactly. I posted the same answer an hour ago but it wasn't well-received don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

You can extract the desired by indexing. All you need to do is convert the string `103` to integers. A string number can be converted to an integer by doing `int(str_num)`. Now once these are integers they are the indices of the alphabets string you want to extract. All the above steps can be condensed into the below code.

`'delimiter'.join(iterable)` join all the elements in the iterable with delimiter.

```
def decrypt(txt,alphabets):
      cipher_text=[alphabets[int(i)] for i in txt]
      return ''.join(cipher_text)
```

---

```
decrypt('103','abcde')
#'bad'
```

Comment: This is probably too condensed for a beginner; or you should explain the code. The ipython I/O formatting obscures the actual code.

Comment: @tripleee Agreed, I added an explanation to it now. And maybe I should write an expressive version for the above for beginners. Thanks for the suggestions.